# appending files in python

Tags: python

I have a homework assignment working with fixed length files:

You will be passed the filename P, firstname F, lastname L, and a new birthday B.

Load the fixed length record file in P, search for F,L in the first and change birthday to B.

```
P= sys.argv[1] 
F= sys.argv[2]
L= sys.argv[3]
B= sys.argv[4]
recordlength = 40
record = [[]]
start = 0
file1 = open(P, 'r')

data = file1.read()
while( (len(data) - start) >= recordlength):
     records= data[start:start + recordlength]
     record.append(records)
     start+= recordlength

for i in range(0,len(record)):
     if F and L in record[i]:
     rec = record[i]


rec = rec[:-8] + B

record[i] = rec
data = "".join(records)
file1 = open(P, 'a+')
file1.write(record[i]) 
file1.close()
```

I should get this output:

```
Adam            Smith           11111985Theodore        Anderson        03201990Monty           Biscuit-Barrel  10181980Adam            Smithers        00000000Ruthy           Anderson        06062010
```

I get this output:

```
Adam            Smith           11111985Theodore        Anderson        03201990Monty           Biscuit-Barrel  10181980Adam            Smithers        10101960Ruthy           Anderson        06062010Adam            Smithers        00000000
```

Instead of replacing this line: Adam            Smithers        10101960, with this line: Adam            Smithers        00000000, it adds this line into the file, leaving the original line.
I'm not sure where my problem is, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: please properly format things. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Where is the example input?

Comment: I don't have the actual input values only the variables that the school assigned, file name = P, First Name = F, Last Name = L, Birthday = B.

Comment: you can reconstruct input from the answer but joey seems a little lazy... its just homework you know... part of learning-curve. SO is not a homework site!

Answer (score 0):

On line 8 you open the file but do not close before opening again on line 20. Try to close before line 20 or open with parameter "a" directly on line 8.